Building Knowledge Graph
I’m a total noob to building knowledge graphs so sorry in advance. I’ve been provided a large dataset with pretty unorthodox data about industrial machines, and I’m trying to create a scheme and knowledge graph to represent the data. I’m pretty read up on RDF, OWL, etc and I’m wondering what software I can use (maybe Apache Jena?) to build an ontology for this data, and then produce a knowledge graph. I wanted to develop the ontology in Protege, but I’m not sure if I can then import that into Apache Jena. If someone could help me get started in the right direction that would be amazing, thanks!!
Also I am required to use GrapQL for querying and PostgreSQL for graph storage.
Also I am required to use GrapQL for querying and PostgreSQL for graph storage.

schema creation aka the ontology itself can be done in Protege - this includes classes, properties and their hierarchy. Populating the knowledge graph then has to be done be some script or mapping based transformation, i.e. something that loads and processes your large dataset.

Indeed, the generated ontology can be processed by Apache Jena. I don't understand what you're trying to do with a Postgres database - this is a relational database. That's not what a knowledge graph usually is considered to be. Indeed, you could load your raw data into Prostgres and then write an OBDA mapping (e.g. using Ontop) to access the data as RDF.

Regarding GraphQL - that's not the default query language for RDF which would be SPARQL. For GraphQL you will need some storage that does support that query language.

You're trying to do something not possible. If you're using postgres, you'll almost certainly be using Apache AGE as your database. This isn't compatible with RDF and instead uses the LPG model, so there's no point in going through with Protege
